# drawing state diagrams / graphs in matplotlib with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata, matplotlib

is there a way to draw the following state diagram in matplotlib?

[image]

Or instead to embed inside a matplotlib figure LaTeX code that draws these diagrams using a package like `tikz`? ideally I would like to annotate the edges and the nodes with LaTeX symbols/math so a solution that embeds LaTeX into a matplotlib figure would be the best.

Comment: I believe this type of graphic might be better suited for a free-form vector art editor such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/).

Comment: @Kelvin not an option. I need it to be programmatically generated as I am making many of them from data. I also want to include matplotlib graphs alongside it

Comment: then I would consider using a library like cairo to draw these graphs programmatically and use something else to render the LaTeX, since LaTeX libraries are much easier to come by than something specially designed to draw this type of thing (which may not even exist yet). You will have to code the rendering of the circles and lines yourself but that is probably for the best because you are more likely to know how these graphics are supposed to look. Cairo also has a built in SVG backend, if you need that.

Comment: @Kelvin but my graphs don't only have state transitions, they also have components drawn in matplotlib (like histograms, etc.). how can i programmatically embed cairo produced graphs in matplotlib?

Comment: Are the histograms combined into the state transition graphs? Otherwise why can’t you just produce the state transition graphs one way and the other graphs the other way?

Comment: @Kelvin they are combined, they are part of the same plot and there are too many of them to assemble later manually. i basically want to make a visualization that has some traditional matplotlib components and some state transitions (that are annotated with mathematical symbols, ideally with LaTeX).

Comment: What's matplotlib?

Comment: What does python do with that ? got it the library matplotlib is written in python. but if you will use Latex i am afraid you shoud forget about that and use some Latex packages like TikZ.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a potential solution using `tikz` package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,petri,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{
    place/.style={
        circle,
        thick,
        draw=black,
        fill=gray!50,
        minimum size=6mm,
    },
        state/.style={
        circle,
        thick,
        draw=blue!75,
        fill=blue!20,
        minimum size=6mm,
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm and 1cm,>=stealth',auto, every place/.style={draw}]
    \node [place] (S1) {S1};
    \coordinate[node distance=1.1cm,left of=S1] (left-S1);
    \coordinate[node distance=1.1cm,right of=S1] (right-S1);

    \draw[->, thick] (left-S1) -- (S1);

    \node [place] (S2) [right=of S1] {S2};
    \node [place] (S3) [node distance=1.5cm,below =of right-S1] {S3};    
    \node [state,initial text=,accepting by double] (S4) [right=of S3] {S4};

    \path[->] (S1) edge [bend left] node {a} (S2);
    \path[->] (S2) edge [bend left] node {b} (S1);
    \path[->] (S2) edge [loop above] node {a} ();
    \path[->] (S3) edge [bend left] node {a} (S1);
    \path[->] (S2) edge [bend left] node {c} (S4);
    \path[->] (S3) edge [bend left] node {b} (S4);
    \path[->] (S4) edge [bend left] node {d} (S3);      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: out]

You could use math symbols in nodes and paths (arcs) labels by putting them between `$ $` for example: `\path[->] (S1) edge [bend left] node {$x^2$} (S2);` and of course you can change the style the way you like thru `\tikzset` settings.

Comment: this is nice but it is unrelated to my question. it made no sense to migrate this question to a TeX forum from stackoverflow. The question is about embedding a TeX generated figure programmatically inside a matplotlib (Python) made graph. I know that TeX can make these state transition diagrams easily which is why I want to call TeX from Python...

Comment: you should explain that to moderators, on this forum we can only provide LaTeX related solutions. I don't know matplotlib, maybe you can exploit the LaTeX code there?

Comment: or you may want to [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatplotlib%5D+call+%5Blatex%5D) since you are looking for the way matplotlib calls LaTeX.